# Shopify Shipping address / Order Cancellation

Tags: shopify

We have a Shopify store here in the Philippines, and 90% of our buyer choose COD(cash on delivery) as a mode of payment, the thing is most of them cancel their order... If we zoom in on the reason of these order cancellations, it's because either shipping address is wrong or incomplete. Is there a way we can solve or lessen this issue? what do you recommend? perhaps a thing that validates the address before proceeding to checkout?

because right now. we proactively call / notify our customer to validate the address, if 3 days pass. we automatically cancel the order.

Comment: This isn't really relevant to SO - but there should be a plugin or something to help. I don't think there'd be a way to guarantee an address is correct, but you could use Google Autocomplete to ensure that the user has a high chance of entering it correctly - https://www.shopify.co.uk/blog/google-autocomplete

Answer (score 3):

Order cancellation due to incorrect shipping address is one of the most common problems faced by store owners in eCommerce.
Talking back to Shopify eCommerce framework, there are many free apps in [Shopify app store](https://apps.shopify.com/) which allows you to edit your order. So you can provide facility to your customers to allow editing shipping address even after the order is placed. Editing the order should be done by store owner its-self.

Refer app on [this](https://apps.shopify.com/search/query?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=edit%20order) page